# android studio - java: package com.google.android.gms.maps does not exist

Tags: android, google-maps

I know these are lot of answer for such question but none worked for me.

I recently imported my Eclipse project to Android Studio (it is not Gradle style). I want to add google map to this project.

I added premission to AndroidManifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

created activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/map" tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

and added this code:

```
package com.myappname.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

/**
 * Created by Dogface on 5/27/2015.
 */
public class GMapActivity extends Activity {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
     * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
     * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
     * <p/>
     * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
     * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
     * <p/>
     * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
     * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
     * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
     * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
     * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
     */
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
     * just add a marker near Africa.
     * <p/>
     * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
     */
    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }

}
```

but when I compile. I get these errors:

```
Error:(6, 35) java: package com.google.android.gms.maps does not exist
Error:(7, 35) java: package com.google.android.gms.maps does not exist
Error:(8, 41) java: package com.google.android.gms.maps.model does not exist
Error:(9, 41) java: package com.google.android.gms.maps.model does not exist
Error:(16, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class GoogleMap
  location: class com.app.GMapActivity
Error:(21, 32) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable activity_maps
  location: class com.app.R.layout
Error:(50, 22) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SupportMapFragment
  location: class com.app.GMapActivity
Error:(50, 42) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getSupportFragmentManager()
  location: class com.app.GMapActivity
Error:(66, 57) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class LatLng
  location: class com.app.GMapActivity
Error:(66, 28) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MarkerOptions
  location: class com.app.GMapActivity
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to add these dependencies in your **build.gradle** file:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.3.0'
```

Comment: I did without success. note that it is not gradle

Answer (score 1):

i experienced thesame thing recently, then changing my dependency to
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
and all other dependencies should be of the same version '10.0.1'

it worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Launch android sdk manager, install Google repository from extras.

You should see the Google maps library in /extras/Google folder.

Import this project as library to your application.

Comment: Is this the recommended way to go in Android Studio?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky that is for eclipse