# Upgrading to play-services-maps to 9.2.1 causes compile error

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I was using play services version 9.0.1 and everything is fine. Changing all play services dependencies to 9.2.1 causes compilation error. I need 9.2.1 because it has a new API that allows me to change the Z index of a marker in a Map. I looked into my local machine and found the AAR of the 9.2.1 play-services-maps and decompiled it and the package com.google.android.gms.maps.model exists and it has a LatLng class. So the class is in the AAR, but it's not finding it.

```
location/geofence/CircularGeofence.java:3: error: package com.google.android.gms.maps.model does not exist

location/geofence/CircularGeofence.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
   private LatLng position;
```

calling ./gradlew app:dependencies show the following. app is the name of my application module in my multi-module project.

```
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.2.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.2.1 (*)
```

Comment: It seems that this kind of [error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489633/android-studio-java-package-com-google-android-gms-maps-does-not-exist) is caused by missing and incorrect use of dependencies, So please make sure that you add the correct and the necessary dependencies in your build.gradle file. Also check the line in which you encountered this error. Check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup), I think it can give you an idea about setting up dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

KENdi is right. What happened was that i have multiple module. The app gradle file has play-services-maps as dependency, but one of my lib module did not; it only have play-services-location. So my guess is that the package went from play-services-location to play-services-maps.